# How to remove error made when adding exit button?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter, button

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3
class login:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("250x250")
        self.root.title("Login")
        self.root.resizable(False,False)

        self.var_username=StringVar()   ##variables
        self.var_password=StringVar()

        username=Label(self.root,text="Username",font=("Bahnschrift SemiBold",15),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=15,y=20) 
        username=Entry(self.root,textvariable=self.var_username,font=("Bahnschrift SemiBold",15),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=125,y=20,width=115)

        password=Label(self.root,text="Password ",font=("Bahnschrift SemiBold",15),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=15,y=60)
        password=Entry(self.root,textvariable=self.var_password,font=("Bahnschrift SemiBold",15),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=125,y=60,width=115)
    
        _exit=Button(self.root,text="exit",command=self.destroy,font=("Bahnschrift SemiBold",15),bg="green",fg="white",cursor="hand2").place(x=125,y=100,width=55,height=28)

if __name__ == "__main__":
root=Tk()
obj=login(root)
root.mainloop()
```

it comes up with a attribute error and im not to sure how to fix it because it works in other pieces of code.

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley The problem, which was trivial, has been already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to change the button command from `self.destroy` to `self.root.destroy`.

```py
Button(self.root,
    text="exit",
    command=self.root.destroy,
    font=("Bahnschrift SemiBold",15),
    bg="green",
    fg="white",
    cursor="hand2").place(x=125, y=100, width=55, height=28)
```

As a side note, doing `label = Label(root, ...).place(x=...)` does not do anything (for any widget). The value of `label` will be stored as `None` and you wont be able to reference that later to change its properties. If this is the goal, then simply: `Label(root, ...).place(x=...)` would work. Otherwise, you'll have to create widgets in one line, and place them in the next line.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? You might want to select an accepted answer and consider closing the question.

Comment: Yes I apologize. I see adding root was the problem